# Hashing a string in python returns the wrong result?

Tags: python

I've been set a homework task by a tutor to create a procedure which hashes a string, or in a sense gives the index of the string in a hash table if it was hashed.

It was supposed to return 11, but returned 0, can someone help me figure out why?

```
def hash_string(keyword, buckets):
    ords = []
    for e in string_to_list(keyword):
        ords.append(ord(e))

    sum_of_ords = ords.pop()

    for e in ords:
        sum_of_ords = sum_of_ords * e

    return sum_of_ords % buckets

print(hash_string('udacity', 12)) # should return 11 but returns 0?
```

Here is the `string_to_list`, I know theres probably a better way, but this is the only way I knew how without using google to search a built in method for this type of thing

```
def string_to_list(str):
    result_list = []
    i = 0

    while i < len(str):
        result_list.append(str[i:i + 1])
        i += 1


    return result_list
```

Here is how my tutor described the answer, but I don't undersand what he is doing with h? Is this just a simplified version of what I'm trying to do?

```
def hash_string(keyword, buckets):
    h = 0
    for c in keyword:
        h = (h + ord(c)) % buckets
    return h
```

Comment: A conversion to `list` isn't necessary to iterate a string. Anyway, you can use `list(your_string)` if you need to.

Comment: Thanks, I knew this come to think of it but must of forgot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you meant to add but multiplied by accident here:

```
sum_of_ords = sum_of_ords * e
```

Change this to:

```
sum_of_ords = sum_of_ords + e
```

Or, with compound assignment:

```
sum_of_ords += e
```

On a side note, you can greatly simplify your function to simply this:

```
def hash_string(keyword, buckets):
    return sum(ord(c) for c in keyword) % buckets
```

Comment: Thanks, this as fixed it. I knew there was a reason why I hadn't used compound assignemnt and that was because I was so used to using it when adding.

Comment: Also (to OP), I have nothing really to add, but just thinking about the difference between the "simplified" version" vs the original attempt: it's useful to print out your intermediate values in your loop (or step through them with a debugger, eg pycharm) to figure out exactly what's going on. If looping thru w/ multiplication (obviously incorrect), _why_ does it return zero? Is the resulting (huge) number overflowing? Or does `mod` return zero? (It's the latter, naturally, since you multiply by the same number in the prev step.) Any pro/con for `mod` in the loop vs after? (Food for thought.)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you used a few unnecessary functions, like using `.pop()`, a `for` loop, and your `hash_string` function can be replaced by using `list(<string>)`.

Example:

```
def hash_string(keyword, buckets):
    ords = []
    for e in list(keyword):
        ords.append(ord(e))

    return sum(ords) % buckets
```

This can be even further simplified to:

```
def hash_string(keyword, buckets):
    return sum([ord(char) for char in list(keyword)]) % buckets
```

Comment: +1 for the `sum(ords)` but I have to give the answer to the first reply, although I do appreciate this answer.

Comment: No problem! It's always good to see different approaches to the same issue.